# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^2+ x+1\rangle$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ denotes the set of all polynomials with coefficients that are $0$ or $1$.

My book hints that there are only $4$ elements in this factor ring, and each nonzero one has an inverse. (Side note, multiplication and addition of coefficients is done modulo $2$ in this factor ring).

My question:

Why are there only $4$ elements in this group? It seems to be there would be infinitely many, since it seems $x^n$is in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, and $x^n + \langle x^2+x+1 \rangle \neq x^m + \langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ if $n\neq m$; why is that incorrect?

Once I understand this I think I will be able to write a proof that shows every element has an inverse, but my confusion on what elements this ring actually contains is preventing me from attempting that now.

Comment: 496 rep, it is maybe time to learn latex

Comment: and note that $x^2=x+1$ in $\mathbb Z_2 [x] / \langle x^2+x+1 \rangle$

Comment: Hint: In $\Bbb Z_2[x],\,$ by division $\,f = (x^2+x+1)q + r \,$ with remainder  $r$ of degree $< 2,\,$ therefore in the quotient ring this implies that $\, f = r\,$ since $\,x^2+x+1 = 0.\ \ $

Comment: Because $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)\in\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ you first get that $x^3+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle=1+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$, and  consequently
$$x^m+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle=x^n+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle\Longleftrightarrow m\equiv n\pmod 3.$$ The other direction of that implication is not immediate from the preceding discussion, but follows from basic properties of cyclic groups.

Comment: Once it is recognized that $F=\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^2+ x+1\rangle$ is $$F=\{|0],[1],[x],[1+x]\}$$ one can note that the mapping $i:F\to G=(\mathbb Z_2)^2$ defined by $$i([0])=(0,0)\quad i([1])=(1,1)\quad i([x])=(1,0)\quad i([1+x])=(0,1)$$ defines an isomorphism between $F$ and the field $G$.

Answer (score 3):

There 4 elements in quotient because the quotient will produce all possible remainders of elements of $Z_2[X]$ divided by $x^2+x+1$, since, by definition of cosets, two elements are in the same coset iff their difference is a multiple of $x^2+1$ i.e., the set $\{ax+b \ : a,b \in Z_2 \}$ contains all cosets, and there are 2 choices for each of $a,b$ for a total of $2(2)=4$ polynomials: Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 2):

The only polynomials that could be in the field would be $0, 1, x, x+1, x^2, x^2+1, x^2+x$. However, 
$$x^2+x = x^2+x - (x^2+x+1) = -1 = 1$$
$$x^2+1 = x^2+1 - (x^2+x+1) = -x = x$$
$$x^2 = x^2 - (x^2+x+1) = -(x+1) = x+1$$ 
so the only elements are $0, 1, x, x+1$.

Comment: Can you explain why x^(n), for n>2 is not an element of Z2[x]? It seems if the only restriction on the polynomials in this set is the coefficient being 0 or 1, then you could easily have x^(n) + <x^(2)+x+1>

Comment: If the degree is more than 2, then you reduce the degree by polynomial division, and any muliple of $x^2+x+1$ is $0$ in this ring so it just goes away.

Comment: I'm still missing something. Why am I reducing the degree by polynomial division? What about this ring implies that is what happens?

Comment: @ignorantcuriosity it's a quotient.   I think you're mistaking it for Z_2 [x^2+x+1].

Comment: $\mathbb Z_2/\langle x^2 + x + 1\rangle$ is a quotient of a ring by the principal ideal generated by $x^2+x+1$. This means that all multiples of $x^2+x+1$ are  $0$, so we can take the largest multiple of $x^2+x+1$ from any polynomial and throw it away, and only the remainder is left. This is where polynomial division comes in play.

Comment: I'm going by the definition that states the quotient ring is equal to {z(x) + <x^(2)+x+1> | z(x)∈Z2[x]}. I'm missing how this implies something like x^5 gets reduced by polynomial division. Can you provide can example of what happens when the element x^(5) + <x^(2)+x+1> is considered?

Comment: Sure! We have that $x^5 = (x^3+x^2)(x^2+x+1) + x^2$, so $x^5+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle = x^2 + (x^3+x^2)(x^2+x+1) + \langle x^2+x+1\rangle$. Then, $x^2+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle = x^2 + (x^3+x^2)(x^2+x+1) + \langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ since their difference is an element of $\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$.

Comment: You've got the wrong definition.   Btw, x^n, n>2 is in Z_2 [x].  You're missing that <x^2+x+1> =O in the quotient...

Comment: @ChrisCuster which definition are you not happy with?

Comment: I'm not happy with {Z_2 [x]+ <x^2+x+1>}. Z_2 [x]/<x^2+x+1> is a quotient. The "/" means quotient. .. –

Comment: That is just notation, not definition. Ring quotients by ideals don't work exactly like polynomial quotients are real number quotients. The elements of the ring $\mathbb Z_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ are the set of equivalence classes of $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ under the equivalence relation that two polynomials fall under the same class if their difference is in the ideal $\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$. We could call the equivalence class of $p(x)$ as $p(x)$, or $p(x) + \langle x^2+x+1\rangle$, $[p(x)]$, or anything really, the notation is up to the OP. The OP's notation is fairly standard.

Comment: @TaisukeYasuda Thank you for the reply. I understand how every other element will be reduced to one of the 4 you listed. I have one other question: How did you generate the list of possible polynomials that could be in the field? I'm missing how we look at the information given in that problem and generate that initial list.

Comment: Those are just all the possible remainders of polynomials in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ after dividing by $x^2+x+1$.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question, but it does answer your title:

$\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field so $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is a PID. And the ideal $(x^2+x+1)$ is prime since $x^2+x+1$ is prime. In fact it is maximal, since prime $=$ maximal in PIDs. And what do you know about maximal ideals?